# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Title]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this Code in Controller

```
Expression<Func<Title, bool>> filterExpr = null;
        Func<IQueryable<Title>, IOrderedQueryable<Title>> orderByFunc = null;           
        List<Title> titles = unitOfWork.TitleRepository.Get(filter: filterExpr, orderBy: orderByFunc, includeProperties: "").ToList();           
        return View("Index", titles);
```

this is the Model

```
public partial class Title
{
    public Title()
    {
        this.NumberTitles = new HashSet<NumberTitle>();
        this.Title1 = new HashSet<Title>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleText { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TitleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NumberTitle> NumberTitles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Title> Title1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Title Title2 { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the View

```
@model IEnumerable<CinemavaadabiatModel.Title>    
<table>    
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TitleText)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

when i run it i get the following error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Title]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Title]'.
where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting the result of the repository get method into a list before returning it to the view. You can either change the type of the model in the view to `List<CinemavaadabiatModel.Title>` or change the controller action to not call `.ToList()` on the `unitOfWork.TitleRepository.Get` method (assuming that it returns an `IEnumerable`):

```
Expression<Func<Title, bool>> filterExpr = null;
Func<IQueryable<Title>, IOrderedQueryable<Title>> orderByFunc = null;           
var titles = unitOfWork.TitleRepository.Get(filter: filterExpr, 
  orderBy: orderByFunc, includeProperties: "");           
return View("Index", titles);
```

It looks as though it returns an `IQueryable` though, so you'd be better off converting this `IQueryable` of domain models into an `IEnumerable` of view models that you can use in the view, thereby keeping the domain and presentation layer concerns separate.

**Update:**

As an alternative, you could create a `TitleViewModel` and add the titles to that instead:

```
public class TitleViewModel
{
    public TitleViewModel()
    {
        this.Titles = new List<CinemavaadabiatModel.Title>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<CinemavaadabiatModel.Title> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller code becomes:

```
Expression<Func<Title, bool>> filterExpr = null;
Func<IQueryable<Title>, IOrderedQueryable<Title>> orderByFunc = null;           
var titles = unitOfWork.TitleRepository.Get(filter: filterExpr, 
  orderBy: orderByFunc, includeProperties: ""); 

// consider using some kind of factory to create your ViewModel 
// if unit testing is a concern
var viewModel = new TitleViewModel { Titles = titles.AsEnumerable() }; 
return View("Index", viewModel);
```

And your view becomes:

```
@model TitleViewModel
<table>    
@foreach (var item in Model.Titles) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TitleText)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: by changing the IEnumerable<CinemavaadabiatModel.Title> to List<CinemavaadabiatModel.Title> i get "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Title]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Title]'"

Comment: and also i change the line in controller to  var titles = unitOfWork.TitleRepository.Get(filter: filterExpr, orderBy: orderByFunc, includeProperties: ""); return View(titles.AsEnumerable()); again i get "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Title]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Title]'. 
"